# Coloring indentation levels

Tags: indentation, coloring

Consider the following two snapshots: The first below is coming from Emacs on Python mode (with Jedi & Elpy)

[image]

This second one below comes from manually photoshopping the previous one to make it easier to distinguish between so many indentation levels.

[image]

Are there any packages that can **help** accomplish the latter effect? In the example above, I used two colors (enough to distinguish indentation levels from their neighbors), but other color schemes using more colors could make navigation even easier.

Note that in Emacs, the indentation character is dictated by:

```
# Insert multiple spaces for indentation:
(setq indent-tabs-mode nil)

# Insert TAB for indentation:
(setq indent-tabs-mode nil)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are a few minor modes that look like they could be tweaked to meet the needs of the original poster:

http://www.github.com/skeeto/visual-indentation-mode

[image]

http://www.github.com/antonj/Highlight-Indentation-for-Emacs

[image]

http://www.github.com/zk-phi/indent-guide

[No screenshot due to no *.gif support when adding links.]

---

There are also a few minor modes out there that create a vertical line that tracks the cursor position, which the original poster may find helpful.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for moving this into an answer.